# Apollo-client without graphql endpoint

Tags: apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo

When I see sample apps which uses `Apollo-client` I see following constructor.When I read [HttpLink](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/link/apollo-link-http/) document, it seems that graphql endpoint must be set as `uri`but in following code, I couldn't find them.

```
export const getApolloClient = (): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> =>
  new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    link: new HttpLink({ credentials: 'same-origin', fetch: customFetch }),
  });
```

My question is why this code work well ?
I am totally novice of that, if someone knows this will you please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HttpLink` constructor option `uri` has a default value of `/graphql`. So as long as that is the correct path it will work without passing a `uri` option into the constructor.

So your example code:

```
HttpLink({ credentials: 'same-origin', fetch: customFetch })
```

is equivalent to

```
HttpLink({ credentials: 'same-origin', fetch: customFetch, uri: '/graphql' })
```